# ResultSetMetaData used with hive gives wrong column length

Tags: java, jdbc, hive, hiveql

I am trying to connect to hive using hive-jdbc in my java program.
I need the column metadata properties like column name,length,etc.
when I use the statement "rsmd.getColumnDisplaySize(i)" i get incorrect outputs.
I get size of integer columns as 11 and String columns as 2147483647.

Is this a bug with hive or jdbc driver?
I have tried hive-jdbc version from 1.1.0 to 2.0 but issue remains the same.
cluster hive version is 1.2.1

Comment: What do you mean incorrect? Those are both correct.

Comment: An integer has max 10 digits + 1 character for `-` sign = 11, the max length of a Java String is 2147483647 characters, and assuming that strings in Hive have no max length that would be OK. So exactly why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: Actually I am working on a ETL product and i am integrating hive with my tool.The confusion was if I can define user defined string length in hive and i get that length from metadata but it seems we cannot define our own string length is Hive.